# CSS last:child no funciona en mi button

Tags: html, css

Tengo una serie de botones que al hacer *click* despliegan un texto, cada botón tiene un `border-bottom`, quiero hacer que todos los botones tengan ese border menos el último.

Este es mi código:

```
 <div class="collapse-container">
      <button  class="collapsible">Primer boton</button>     
      <p>Primer Texto</p>
      <button  class="collapsible">Segundo boton</button>
      <p>Segundo Texto</p>
      <button  class="collapsible">Tercer boton</button>
      <p>Tercer Texto</p>
 </div>
```

Mi css es el siguiente:

```
.collapsible{
  background-color: white;
  transition: border-bottom 1s, background-color .6s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.collapse-container button:last-child p{border-bottom: none;}
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué no funciona?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un par de cosas mal en ese selector:

Por una parte tienes una **p** al final, lo que significa que intentas acceder a un párrafo dentro del botón.

Aún quitando la *p* no funcionaría ya que `:last-child` selecciona el último de una serie de hermanos y el botón no es el último, el último es el párrafo.
Para seleccionar el último elemento de un tipo concreto debes usar la pseudoclase `:last-of-type`:

```css
.collapsible{
  background-color: white;
  transition: border-bottom 1s, background-color .6s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.collapse-container button:last-of-type{border-bottom: none;}
```

```html
 <div class="collapse-container">
      <button  class="collapsible">Primer boton</button>     
      <p>Primer Texto</p>
      <button  class="collapsible">Segundo boton</button>
      <p>Segundo Texto</p>
      <button  class="collapsible">Tercer boton</button>
      <p>Tercer Texto</p>
 </div>
```